# Column level encryption in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know Snowflake by default encrypts data at rest. But I wanted to know if there is a built-in feature to encrypt a column value and store it in Snowflake tables. Or is it something that I need to code using snowpark and store as a procedure.

Comment: Yes there are encryption functions. I would suggest starting by reading the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you read up on the Dynamic Data Masking that is available natively in Snowflake, which allows you to encrypt data to specific roles or all roles, as needed.  And if there in an external encryption tool via API that you'd like to use, Dynamic Data Masking can leverage that API via an External Function.  You shouldn't need Snowpark or a Stored Procedure to accomplish this.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-column-ddm.html